# View is Not masking to Parent View

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, ipad-2

[image: Please Refer This Screen Shot]

I've added Line View to one Content View, while adding on Content View ,i set `UIViewAutoResizingMask` ,but my view is cutting to Parent View for minute of seconds.

```
lineView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin;
```

Comment: if you put up a picture of what is happening, and what you want to happen. I can help.

Comment: Also, that line of code you have is rare that it helps. You generally don't have variable horizontal margins AND variable width.

Comment: What does minutes and seconds has to do with it? You know that the word mark refers to a bitmask and not to masking the view, right? That property is used for resizing the view.

Comment: Thanks All For Reply, I need Red Colored Line Should mask with Right Side Border.